# Visual Studio Inline assembler not working as expected

Tags: c, assembly

Is

```
MOV MUL_AXB[EBX * 4], EAX
```

supposed to actually change the effective MUL_AXB address?

I have declared MUL_AXB as

```
int* MUL_AXB;
```

on the global scope after the using statements and i have assigned it a value with

```
MUL_AXB = (int*) memset(malloc(size), 0, size);
```

Any insight on this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing will write in memory somewhere past the `mul_axb` pointer, causing bad things to happen.

To actually write into the allocated array, you need to load the pointer into a register first. Assuming this is 32-bit code:

```
mov edx, [mul_axb]
mov [edx + ebx*4], eax
```